# Отобразить доступные звуковые устпройства в listBox с помощью bass.dll

Tags: c#, .net

Перешел на c# не так давно. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующем.
Ранее в делфи я получал список устройств таким образом:

> procedure TForm1.sListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
> begin
> if (sListBox1.ItemIndex= -1) or (Bass_Init(StrToInt(sListBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[sListBox1.ItemIndex]),44100,0,handle, nil)=False) then BASS_Free();
> end;

Но как отобразить доступные звуковые устпройства в listBox на C# понять не могу

Comment: И в чем конкретно у вас трудности? Не знаете, как добавить в `ListBox`, или взять из него данные? Да все +- также, только названия чуть другие, добавить например `.Items.Add(...)`, взять по индексу `.Items[...]`, выделенный индекс `.SelectedIndex`, выделенный объект `.SelectedItem`. Или вы не знаете, как работать с библиотекой? Да все тоже самое, берите прям и копируйте, методы ведь одни. Или вы не знаете как через Bass.dll получить устройства? `Bass.BASS_GetDeviceInfos();`? Собственно, я думаю вы поняли, что раздуваете из мухи слона, и без каких-либо попыток сразу просите помощь...

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за подсказку. Сделал таким образом, все получилось.

```
    BASS_DEVICEINFO info = new BASS_DEVICEINFO();
for (int n = 0; Bass.BASS_GetDeviceInfo(n, info); n++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(info.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Почему `BASS_GetDeviceInfo`, а не `BASS_GetDeviceInfos`? Я ведь не тот метод дал. `foreact (var device in Bass.BASS_GetDeviceInfos()){ listBox1.Items.Add(.....); }`